# How is $e^z$ the only function that is entire with the property $f'(z) = f(z)$ and $f(0) = 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

How is the function $e^z$ the only function that is entire and has the property $f'(z) = f(z)$ and that $f(0) = 1$ but how would you exactly prove it?

where $e^z = e^x(\cos y + i\sin y)$

Comment: What do you mean? The function $f(z)=z$ admits a derivative at every point in the complex plane. Maybe you mean ... the only function that is entire and has the property $f'(z)=f(z), \ f(0)=1$.

Comment: It isn't the only function that admits a derivative at every point in the complex plane. Polynomials, for example.

Comment: For the "Also..." question, it depends on how you defined $e^z$.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews I'm sorry. I'm just trying to understand whats written in my textbook. When defining $e^z$ what do you exactly mean?

Comment: Every function has a definition.What is the definition of the function $e^z$ that your book uses?

Comment: Which textbook??? As others have noted, oodles of functions are differentiable everywhere.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews I think what P.. mentioned might be what I'm trying to get at. But the definition of $e^z = e^x(cosy + isiny)$. If that is what you are wondering.

Comment: But even then, it depends on knowing properties of the real function $e^x$.

Answer (score 2):

Think about any function with $f'(z)=f(z)$ and $f(0)=1$. Derive the product $f(z)e^{-z}$ with the product rule: 
$$
(f(z)e^{-z})'=f'(z)e^{-z}+f(z)(e^{-z})'=f(z)e^{z}-f(z)e^{z}=0
$$
Thus $f(z)e^{-z}$ is constant, $\exists c\in\mathbb{C}: f(z)e^{-z}=c\quad \forall z\in\mathbb{C}$
Hence $f(z)\equiv ce^{z}$. Since $1=f(0)=ce^{0}=c$, we have $f(z)\equiv e^{z}$.

Answer (score 0):

As
$$1 = f(0) = f'(0) = f''(0) = \cdots$$
the Taylor series of $f$ will be
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!}.$$